# RuntimeError: Table column/cell width not specified, unable to continue

Tags: python, html, django, pdf, fpdf

I am trying to create a PDF file by using pyfpdf in python django. the following code snippet I am trying to genrate the pdf of html code.

```
    from fpdf import FPDF, HTMLMixin
    class WriteHtmlPDF(FPDF, HTMLMixin):
        pass

    html = f"""<h3>xxxxx</h3>
 <div style="border:1px solid #000">
     <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
         <tr><th width=20 align="left">xxxxxxxx:</th><td>xxxxxxxx</td></tr>
         <tr><th width=20 align="left">xxxxxxxx:</th><td>xxxxxxxxx</td></tr>
         <tr><th width=20 align="left">xxxxxxxx:</th><td>xxxxxxxxx</td></tr>
         <tr><th width=20 align="left">xxxxxxxx:</th><td>xxxxxxxxx</td></tr>
     </table>
 </div>
 <div>
     <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" align="center" width=100>
         <tr>
             <td width=33>xxxxxx: 1</td>
             <td width=33>xxxxxx: 0</td>
             <td width=33>xxxxxx: 1</td>
         </tr>
     </table>
 </div>
 <table style="border: 1px solid black;" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width=100>
     <thead align="center">
         <tr style="background-color: #6AB9F7;">
             <th>Sr No.</th>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>xxxxx</th>
             <th>xxxxx</th>
             <th>xxxxx</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody align="center">
         <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>xxxxxx</td>
             <td>xxxxxx</td>
             <td>xxxxxx</td>
             <td>xxxxxx</td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
"""
    pdf = WriteHtmlPDF()
    # First page
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.write_html(html)
    pdf.output('html.pdf', 'F')
```

I am using the multiple tables in my HTML code and facing the problem while creating the PDF. following is the error, which I am getting.

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fpdf/html.py", line 72, in handle_data
web_1       |     l = [self.table_col_width[self.table_col_index]]
web_1       | IndexError: list index out of range
web_1       | 
web_1       | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
web_1       | 
web_1       | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
web_1       |     response = get_response(request)
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
web_1       |     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
web_1       |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
web_1       |     return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
web_1       |   File "./eauction/views.py", line 638, in get_login_report
web_1       |     pdf.write_html(result_data)
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fpdf/html.py", line 401, in write_html
web_1       |     h2p.feed(text)
web_1       |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/html/parser.py", line 111, in feed
web_1       |     self.goahead(0)
web_1       |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/html/parser.py", line 163, in goahead
web_1       |     self.handle_data(unescape(rawdata[i:j]))
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fpdf/html.py", line 74, in handle_data
web_1       |     raise RuntimeError("Table column/cell width not specified, unable to continue")
web_1       | RuntimeError: Table column/cell width not specified, unable to continue
```

I tried [GitHub](https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf/issues/18) solutions, but still getting same error

Comment: The given code does not generate any error. Please provide the snippet that does.

Comment: @user5173426 updated the question and added snippet

Comment: if the answer posted below helped, you may accept it! cheers